# row to column conversion in sql

Tags: sql

Suppose I am having 3 set of records like

```
Actno    Sufix   Amount
000005   230     101000
000005   535     100000
000005   630     -500000
000009   230     222000
000009   535     120000
000009   635     220000
```

I need to display it as

```
000005   230   101000   535   100000   630   -500000
000009   230   222000   535   120000   635   220000
```

Is that possible in SQL? Can anyone please help me regarding this?

Comment: Just SQL?  Or are you using something like PHP to display it?

Comment: What for you want to do this ?

Comment: i need to do different calculations based on each sufix and generate report

Answer (score 1):

If you know that you have three registrations for each Actno you can do this

```
;with cte as
(
  select *,
    row_number() over(partition by Actno order by Sufix) as rn
  from [YourTable]
)  
select
  C.Actno,
  min(C1.Sufix),
  min(C1.Amount),
  min(C2.Sufix),
  min(C2.Amount),
  min(C3.Sufix),
  min(C3.Amount)
from cte as C
  inner join cte as C1
    on C.Actno = C1.Actno and C1.rn = 1
  inner join cte as C2
    on C.Actno = C2.Actno and C2.rn = 2
  inner join cte as C3
    on C.Actno = C3.Actno and C3.rn = 3
group by C.Actno 
order by C.Actno
```

Answer (score 0):

No, it's not possible in SQL.

It's also not what SQL is intended for; presentation is not SQL's job.

If you feel you need to get column data into rows, then there is something about your idea for organising your data that doesn't suit relational databases. That's where you should look.

Comment: thank you for the response. I tried first in excel, pivoting and all....but there also cudnt find solution...so thought of organising in sql..

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind that your aggregated rows are on string (and you're using Oracle), I used to do something like this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION APPEND_FIELD(sqlstr in varchar2,
                                     sep    in varchar2)
return varchar2 is
ret varchar2(4000) := '';
TYPE cur_typ IS REF CURSOR;
rec   cur_typ;
field varchar2(4000);
begin
OPEN rec FOR sqlstr;
LOOP
  FETCH rec
    INTO field;
    EXIT WHEN rec%NOTFOUND;
    ret := ret || field || sep;
END LOOP;
if length(ret) = 0 then
    RETURN '';
else
    RETURN substr(ret, 1, length(ret) - length(sep));
end if;
end;
/

select 
  actno, 
  sufix, 
  amount, 
  APPEND_FIELD('select sufix '''||' '||'''amount 
                  from table tt
                 where tt.actno = '||t.actno||' and sufix != 230 ',' ')
   from table t 
  where sufix=230;
```

HTH